# how to install hp scanner in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation

i have tried to install hp scan jet 200 scanner in Ubuntu 12.04 but fail to install. help me how to install scanner.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! HP scanners normally work out of the box and do not require installation. Could you please [edit] your question including the procedure you tried to install the scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very detailed and lacks what you'd like to install.  I'll give you a generic answer.  Many scanners "Just Work" under Ubuntu.  Some don't (I installed an Epson All-In-One, that required a proprietary driver called iScan), but many do.

The first thing to try is connect the scanner.  These days, that almost certainly is USB.  (Other options are SCSI or parallel, but I doubt you'll encounter that often).

At this point start the application called "Simple Scan".  It it what it is: a small application that does scanning without much configurability, but it covers most uses (honest!).  Try scanning with that.  It it works, tadaaa!, you have a working scanner.
If it doesn't you will probably have to install something from the manufacturer.  Obviously, it is impossible for me to say what and how to do that without more information.

Finally, I'd like to point out a third option that I have used for certain expensive scanners that don't have drivers and aren't supported on OS X or Windows either any more. It's a program called "[VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/)" sold by Hamrick software.  It has a huge compatibility list (it works on almost any scanner), is cross-platform, and the license is affordable and rather reasonable in terms.
I do not have any relation to Hamrick software, I am just a satisfied customer.